# access variables from outside .each() jquery

Tags: jquery, variables, each

I am trying to access a variable set outside of an each() function and but I do not know why it does not work

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var color = "blue";
  $('.list-item').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('list-'+color)){
      console.log('found');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Where's `$` in `('.list-item')` ?

Comment: Why the `.hasClass()`? -> `$(".list-item.list-" + color)`

Comment: Post the relevant markup

Comment: the $ is there originally. I must have forgotten it here.

Comment: Can you share your HTML code as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly your jQuery object is missing a `$` so you're getting a syntax error which is why your code doesn't work.

That being said you can improve the logic here as the `each()` loop is redundant; you can select the element directly and check the `length` property of the resulting jQuery object. Try this:

```
var color = "blue";
if ($('.list-item.list-' + color).length) {
    console.log('found');
}
```